# jquery text highlights with html preservation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create jquery which will allow to highlight selected text by mouse including several selection (e.g. three separate sections). Currently I have [the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/6eem3why/1/), but experienced the following issues with this code:

1. it allows single selection (while I would like to have a possibility to select first sentence, then third one and have them both marked independently).
2. as it works based on regexp'es, when I select single letter (e.g. 'a') all letters are selected.
3. styles (e.g. bold) are not preserved.

Please advise how I can improve this script to address above issues. 
Thank you!

**js code:**

```
enableHighlights(".mainPane");


function enableHighlights(thisDiv) {
    $(thisDiv).on("mouseup", function () {
        var selectedText = getSelectionText();
        var selectedTextRegExp = new RegExp(selectedText);
        var text = $(this).text().replace(selectedTextRegExp, "<span class='red'>" + selectedText + "</span>");
        $(this).html(text);
        $('#selection').html(selectedText);
    });
}

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is as close as I could get to the correct answer: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6eem3why/2/)**

```
enableHighlights(".mainPane");

var sText=[],
    sStart=[];
function enableHighlights(thisDiv) {
    var initialHTML=$(thisDiv).html();
    var theHTML='';
    $(thisDiv).on("mouseup", function () {
        var selectedText = getSelectionText();
        var selectedRange=getSelectionRange($(thisDiv)[0]);
        sText.push(selectedText);
        sStart.push(selectedRange.start);
        theHTML=initialHTML;
        $.each(sText,function(i,v){
            var selectedTextRegExp = new RegExp(v);
            var usingHTML=theHTML.slice(sStart[i]-1);
            var text = usingHTML.replace(selectedTextRegExp, "<span class='red'>" + v + "</span>");
            theHTML=theHTML.slice(0,sStart[i]-1)+text;
        });
        $(this).html(theHTML);
        $('#selection').html(selectedText);
    });
}

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
    return text;
}
function getSelectionRange(element) {
    var start = 0, end = 0;
    var sel, range, priorRange;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        priorRange = range.cloneRange();
        priorRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        start = priorRange.toString().length;
        end = start + range.toString().length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
            (sel = document.selection).type != "Control") {
        range = sel.createRange();
        priorRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        priorRange.moveToElementText(element);
        priorRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
        start = priorRange.text.length;
        end = start + range.text.length;
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}
```

the only problem is when you try to select a bold and normal text together which I was unable to find a workaround!

Comment: Hi Amin, Thank you a lot for looking at it. What I can see is that if I start selecting letters (one by one) in the last word (Ipsum) then strange things start to happen;). I am wondering if there is anything ready that I would reuse, as it looks to me it is not simple task to make such functionality up and running. What do you think ?

Comment: take a look at this link, it might help http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/